# mkdir -p skips creating a middle directory on the Azure Datalake

Tags: shell, azure, azure-data-lake, databricks

Why does this consistently make a path in Databricks

```
%sh
/dbfs/mnt/datalake/data/staging/steve/3/14
```

No matter what it drops creating the `2019`.

If I leave out `/2019` then it drops creating the `3`.

.

Here is my Cmd

```
mkdir -p /dbfs/mnt/datalake/data/staging/steve/2019/3/14
```

Comment: I don't know what Azure Datalake is, but if `mkdir` on it is supposed to be POSIX compliant then you need to report it as a bug [POSIX `mkdir`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mkdir.html)

Comment: @SteveLyle-CSG - I think you replied to the wrong person.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks Dave. The %sh command is being executed in a Databricks notebook, which runs on Linux Ubuntu, and is an action against Azure Data Lake Storage (ADLS) integrated to Ubuntu as a mounted storage. This is Microsoft's principal architecture for working with Spark/Hiv in Azure.